# How to prevent Tomcat from shutting down when saxon xslt processor throws runtime errors?

Tags: java, tomcat, xslt, saxon

I am using saxon to transform a .xhtml file in my web application. When saxon tries to transform a .xhtml document which is not well formed....it throws the following error :-

```
Error on line 665 column 231 of ABXDE123nual-Filing.xhtml:
  SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Element type "span" must be followed by either
  attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
Recoverable error on line 62 of someXSLT.xsl:
  SXXP0003: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:
  file:/C:/Users/ruowier/AppData/Local/Temp/temp1231700079536768843678/ABXDE123nual-Filing.xhtml; lineNumber: 665; columnNumber: 231; Element type "span" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
Error on line 62 of someXSLT.xsl:
  FODC0002: Failed to load document
  file:/C:/Users/ruowier/AppData/Local/Temp/temp1231700079536768843678/ABXDE123nual-Filing.xhtml
Transformation failed: Run-time errors were reported
```

and soon after tomcat server gets stopped....

```
Aug 26, 2019 10:20:16 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Unable to find 'struts.multipart.saveDir' property setting. Defaulting to javax.servlet.context.tempdir
Aug 26, 2019 10:20:30 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Aug 26, 2019 10:20:30 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Aug 26, 2019 10:20:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Aug 26, 2019 10:20:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 1 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [default]
Aug 26, 2019 10:20:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 1 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [default]
Aug 26, 2019 10:20:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 1 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [default]
Aug 26, 2019 10:20:32 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/somePortal] is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation.
Aug 26, 2019 10:20:32 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/somePortal] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@5179827b]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@381bab5]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Aug 26, 2019 10:20:32 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/somePortal] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@5179827b]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@cb13461]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Aug 26, 2019 10:20:32 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/somePortal] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@4c2bf1fc]) and a value of type [org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher] (value [org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher@51dcc858]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Aug 26, 2019 10:20:32 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/somePortal] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@5f8694c4]) and a value of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext@5a91a169]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Aug 26, 2019 10:20:32 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/somePortal] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@49260fd6]) and a value of type [net.sf.saxon.expr.sort.LRUCache] (value [net.sf.saxon.expr.sort.LRUCache@7e8f80a2]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Aug 26, 2019 10:20:32 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/somePortal] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@5179827b]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@15440b03]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Aug 26, 2019 10:20:32 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Aug 26, 2019 10:20:37 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint shutdownExecutor
WARNING: The executor associated with thread pool [http-apr-8080] has not fully shutdown. Some application threads may still be running.
Aug 26, 2019 10:20:37 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Aug 26, 2019 10:20:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Aug 26, 2019 10:20:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
```

I tried to catch the errors by surrounding the transformation statements with catch block as follows....but it doesn't seem to work....

```
  try {
            .
            .
            .
            .
            
            String[] args  = new String[7];
            args[0] = "-xsl:"+xsltPath;
            args[1] = "-o:"+outputPath;
            args[2] = "-it:main";
            args[3] = "delimiter="+delimiter;
            args[4] = "errPropPath="+errPropPath; 
            args[5] = "xsltFolderPath="+xsltFolderPath; 
            args[6] = "inputfiles="+inputPath+"";
            
            //SAXON gets called over here...
            Transform.main(args);
            
            .
            .
            .
            .
            
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            logger.debug("exception",e1);
        }catch(Error e ){
            logger.debug("error",e);
        }
```

Comment: You have to [edit] your post and include the Tomcat log that shows how Tomcat is crashing.

Comment: added Tomcat logs that shows Tomcat is crashing..

Comment: That looks to me as if you try to call Saxon's command line entry point from your Java code, the usual way to call Saxon from Java code is using the s9api package as described in http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/embedding/s9api-transformation.html, there you should be able to handle and log errors.

Answer (score 2):

You are invoking the transformation using the command line interface:

```
Transform.main(args);
```

By default this closes the Java VM (using quit()) when a dynamic error occurs in the transformation. There is an option `-quit:off` to change this behaviour.

However, this is not the recommended way to invoke Saxon from a Java application. The recommended ways are to use either the JAXP API or the s9api API. Both are documented at http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!using-xsl/embedding

Using an API gives you far more control over the way the transformation runs. For starters, if you use the same stylesheet once to transform multiple documents, it allows you to compile the stylesheet once and use it repeatedly. This is important because compiling the stylesheet often dominates the transformation time.